# Trying to draw a grid of circles that fill the viewport, but the grid starts at the center

Tags: java, libgdx

I am using a ShapeRenderer to draw circles at specific X,Y coordinates, starting at 0,0 and filling out to 50,50 with a gap between.

Am i missing something obvious here?

I have created an Array of points like this:

> [[0,0],[0,2]...[50,48],[50,50]]

Here is the relevant code:

```
public void create() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(100, 100, camera);
        renderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        grid = new PointGrid(50, 50);
    }
```

```
public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        renderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        renderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        renderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        for (int i = 0; i < grid.getPoints().size; i++) {
            Vector2 point = grid.getPoints().get(i);
            renderer.circle(point.x, point.y, 1, 32);
        }

        renderer.end();

        camera.update();
    }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I should add here that I am fairly new to LibGDX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a Viewport to manage your camera, you need to call `viewport.update(...)` in your resize method.

```
public void resize (int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height, true);
}
```

Passing `true` to the update method will put 0,0 at the bottom left of the screen instead of the center.

If you want gaps between your circles, you need a smaller radius or a bigger step between them. Right now you have a 2-unit step between them and they have a 2-unit diameter so they are touching each other.

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the true in the resize method.  Dot size was just trying to get something on the screen, their going to be more spaced out eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure camera is by default looking at 0,0 which means it will put 0,0 at the center.
So you want to set the position of your camera at - SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, - SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2

You can get Screen size with Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / getHeight()